# There is an error when calling update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= form_for(@object, url: obj_path) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :Flow_ID %>:
    <%= select_tag "flow", options_from_collection_for_select(@flows, "id", "name") %><br><br>
    <%= f.label :Object_Type_ID %>:
    <%= select_tag "object_type", options_from_collection_for_select(@object_types, "id", "name") %><br><br>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br><br>
    <%= f.label :label %>
    <%= f.text_field :label %><br><br>
    <%= f.submit "Update Object", class: "btn btn-success"  %><br>
    <%= link_to "Back", objs_path %>

<% end %>
```

**This is edit.html.erb**

```
class ObjsController < ApplicationController

   def update
     @object = Obj.find(params[:id])
     @object.flow_id = params[:flow]
     @object.object_type_id = params[:object_type]
     @object.update(object_params)
     redirect_to objs_url
   end

  private
   def object_params
     params.require(:object).permit(:name, :label)
   end
end
```

This is objs_controller.rb.

When I click update button, object_params is missing. Anyone knows what I have a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean with "missing"?

Comment: What is the error? Please post it.

Comment: error is 'param is missing or the value is empty: object'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> param is missing or the value is empty: object

You should change

```
def object_params
  params.require(:object).permit(:name, :label)
end
```

to

```
def object_params
  params.require(:obj).permit(:name, :label)
end
```

<s>As you model is `Obj` not `Object`</s>

If you look into the `params` hash, you will see it with `:obj` key. So you need to use `:obj` not `:object`

Comment: Thanks for answer, But if I do like that, create action doesn't work.

Comment: @Pinaev What is the error you get? Also, you just can't polling another questions in the comments. You need to accept the answer and move on and ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

If your model name is Obj, then you have a mismatch. Either change Obj to Object or Object to Obj. I can further update my answer based on your response. Also provide the complete error log in your question.

Change the line

```
params.require(:object).permit(:name, :label)
```

to

```
params.require(:obj).permit(:name, :label)
```

That should solve the problem. 
[strong parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, but Obj is a model name. This is no relationship between Obj and Object.